# Not able to focus the first element of the menubar on page load

Tags: jquery

How to set focus of the first li of the menu using jquery

here is what i am trying :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#check').find('li').first().focus();
    });
```

check is the id of the menubar

HTML :

```
<nav id="check" class="uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-flex-item-1 uk-flex-right">
  <ul class="uk-navbar-nav uk-hidden-small">
    <li tabindex="0"><a href="/demo1-home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li></li>...other menu elements
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you post HTML?

Comment: @Niladri Done..

Comment: so what is the issue here? do you want to click on the navigation link?

Comment: Your code is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/4ows55bf/

Comment: not working for the website that i am working on what can be the issue behind this?? @SureshPonnukalai

Answer (score 0):

Focus on `<a>` instead like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $($('#check').find('a')[0]).focus();
});
```